# Symfony JsonResponse ignoring defined HTTP code and only responses 200

Tags: php, nginx, silex

I'm trying change HTTP code in Response but I always receive 200.
the code below is resumed a lot with both tests:

```
$app->put('/hdc/v1/pagamento/{pagamento_id}', function($pagamento_id, Request $request) use ($app) {

    $pagamento = Pagamento::find($pagamento_id);

    return new JsonResponse(["message"=>"error"],400); // returns 200
}




$app->put('/hdc/v1/pagamento/{pagamento_id}', function($pagamento_id, Request $request) use ($app) {

//    $pagamento = Pagamento::find($pagamento_id);

    return new JsonResponse(["message"=>"error"],400); // returns 400
}
```

Interacting with the model, JsonResponse is impacted. Why?

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6vHU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awkward!

My entity file Pagamento had

```
?>
```

in the file bottom.
it was sending 200 code header when the Pagamento::find method was called.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't use the good method. See the [silex doc](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/usage.html#json) :

```
<?php
$app->put('/hdc/v1/pagamento/{pag_id}', function($pag_id, Request $request) use ($app) {
return $app->json(array('message' => 'error'), 400);
});
```

Comment: I tried with this solution and it work. You have override error with Silex ?

Comment: There is no error, Thomas. In fact, the response has 200 code. But i want set up 400 in response.

Comment: My question was have you added some after middleware or before middleware or anything else ?

Comment: bull's eye, @Thomaz! In order to made easy the API I used this @before: `    if (0 === strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
        $form = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $request->request->replace(is_array($form) ? $form : array());
    }
`

Comment: @Thomaz, bad news... the problem keeps annoying me... Question edited.